# getline для работы с файлами не работает

Tags: c++

Работаем с файлом MyFile.txt. Почему-то после ввода 1 консоль не ждёт, чтобы я ввёл текст (из-за getline(cin, msg)), а игнорирует это и заканчивает свою работу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "MyFile.txt";
    fstream fs;
    fs.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (fs.is_open())
    {
        int value;
        string msg;
        cout << "Type 1 to write sth!" << endl;
        cin >> value;
        if (value == 1)
        {
            getline(cin, msg);
            fs << msg;
        }
    }
    fs.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: когда я использую вместо getline(cin, msg) cin >> msg; то всё работает, но проблема в том, что cin >> считывает до первого проблема, а мне надо всю строку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После команды `cin >> value` нужно убрать оставшийся в буфере конец строки.

```
cin >> value ;
cin . ignore ( std::numeric_limitsstd::streamsize::max(), '\n');
```

Ответ взят из источников информации :

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

> Notes When consuming whitespace-delimited input (e.g. int n; std::cin
> >> n;) any whitespace that follows, including a newline character, will be left on the input stream. Then when switching to line-oriented
> input, the first line retrieved with getline will be just that
> whitespace. In the likely case that this is unwanted behaviour,
> possible solutions include:
>
> An explicit extraneous initial call to getline
>
> Removing consecutive
> whitespace with std::cin >> std::ws
>
> Ignoring all leftover characters
> on the line of input with
> cin.ignore(std::numeric_limitsstd::streamsize::max(), '\n');

[getline() skipping first even after clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186568/getline-skipping-first-even-after-clear)

[istream::ignore and getline() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8105847/4827341)